# Highchart get data and change column color on click drilldown data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get y data of each point and change the color of drilldown columns. This fiddle gets data from both series. How do I get that? Consider the code snippet below.

```js
$(function() {
    Highcharts.Tick.prototype.drillable = function () {};
    $('#columnChart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                events:{
                    click: function (event) {
                       alert(event.point.y)
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderColor: '#AAA',
            headerFormat: null,
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span><br/>Total clicks: <b>{point.y:.0f}</b>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'URLs',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Game of Thrones',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Game of Thrones'
            }, {
                name: 'SHERLOCK',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'SHERLOCK'
            }, {
                name: 'Flash',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Flash'
            }, {
                name: 'Daredevil',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Daredevil'
            }, {
                name: 'The Fosters',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'The Fosters'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            activeAxisLabelStyle: {
                textDecoration: 'none',
                fontStyle: 'italic',
                color: '#54BDDC'
            },
            activeDataLabelStyle: {
                textDecoration: 'none',
                fontStyle: 'italic',
                color: '#fff'
            },
            drillUpButton: {
                relativeTo: 'spacingBox',
                position: {
                    y: 0,
                    x: 0
                },
                theme: {
                    fill: 'white',
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    stroke: 'silver',
                    r: 0,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#fff',
                            stroke: '#039',
                            fill: '#2AABD2'
                        },
                        select: {
                            color: '#fff',
                            stroke: '#039',
                            fill: '#bada55'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Game of Thrones',
                id: 'Game of Thrones',
                data: [
                    [
                        'Sep 9, 2016',
                        24.13
                    ],
                    [
                        'Sep 15, 2016',
                        17.2
                    ],
                    [
                        'Sep 21, 2016',
                        8.11
                    ],
                    [
                        'Sep 29, 2016',
                        5.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'Oct 03, 2016',
                        1.06
                    ],
                    [
                        'Oct 06, 2016',
                        0.5
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'SHERLOCK',
                id: 'SHERLOCK',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v40.0',
                        5
                    ],
                    [
                        'v41.0',
                        4.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v42.0',
                        3.68
                    ],
                    [
                        'v39.0',
                        2.96
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36.0',
                        2.53
                    ],
                    [
                        'v43.0',
                        1.45
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31.0',
                        1.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v35.0',
                        0.85
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38.0',
                        0.6
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32.0',
                        0.55
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37.0',
                        0.38
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33.0',
                        0.19
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34.0',
                        0.14
                    ],
                    [
                        'v30.0',
                        0.14
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Flash',
                id: 'Flash',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v35',
                        2.76
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36',
                        2.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37',
                        2.31
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34',
                        1.27
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38',
                        1.02
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31',
                        0.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33',
                        0.22
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32',
                        0.15
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Daredevil',
                id: 'Daredevil',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        2.56
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.1',
                        0.77
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.1',
                        0.42
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.0',
                        0.3
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.1',
                        0.29
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.26
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.2',
                        0.17
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'The Fosters',
                id: 'The Fosters',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v12.x',
                        0.34
                    ],
                    [
                        'v28',
                        0.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v27',
                        0.17
                    ],
                    [
                        'v29',
                        0.16
                    ]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="columnChart"></div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djmsuman/1mrvw3fw/2/

Comment: You want to get y data before the drilldown or after the drilldown? Also, do you wanto change the color of the columns after drilldown? You can specify colors for each series separately, as well as events. https://jsfiddle.net/1mrvw3fw/6/

Comment: Yes I want it after drilldown. You got it correctly. In the fiddle it is getting y data from both before and after drilldown points. Before drilldown it wont change color and after drilldown it should. @morganfree

Comment: In your fiddle I could see color has changed to yellow. the color change event will occur after clicking on particular point (after drilldown). Could you please help buddy? @morganfree